# SQL*Plus spooling to .xls/.html help, need tables to be side by side

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

So I have my settings as:

```
    set entmap off
    set feedback off
    set verify off
    set und off
    set pagesize 100
    set linesize 200
    set markup html on
    preformat off
    entmap on
    spool on
    spool \\...\...\test.xls

    ......... 4 select queries ..........

    set markup html off
    spool off
```

The output shows the 4 tables stacked vertically in the .xls spreadsheet aligned to the left starting at A1, but is there a way for me to have solely the first 3 vertically stacked, with the 4th table to the right of the 3rd/lowest table which would start at cell T23?

Comment: You could UNION the last two queries together and format the select list to output the columns from the third query first, followed by the columns from the fourth query.

Comment: Hm, whats the command for that? And wouldn't the union pretty much just stack the two data sets on top of each other?

Comment: It would be UNION ALL, but after playing with it a bit my thinking changed. Really needs a FULL OUTER JOIN. See my answer below.

Comment: If I understand your problem, look at *nix utility `paste` to merge the individual files in a separate step, outside of your sqlplus script. This will be a fragile result. Writing a real program to do the merge will help you control error cases you can identify during development, but may still have problems in the long run. The 2 solutions below seem like more robust solutions. Offering this in case this is a one-off that is meant to be proof of concept. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this

```
-- Query 1

SELECT *
  FROM TABLE1
  WHERE WHATEVER = SOMETHING_ELSE;

-- Query 2

SELECT *
  FROM TABLE2
  WHERE YADA_YADA = THIS_N_THAT;

-- Queries 3 and 4

SELECT NVL(q3.RNUM, q4.RNUM) AS RNUM, q3.COL1, Q3.COL2, Q3.COL3,
       ' ' AS SPACER,
       Q4.COL4, Q4.COL5, Q4.COL6
  FROM (SELECT ROWNUM AS RNUM, COL1, COL2, COL3,
               NULL AS COL4, NULL AS COL5, NULL AS COL6
          FROM TABLE3) q3
  FULL OUTER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM AS RNUM, NULL AS COL1, NULL AS COL2, NULL AS COL3,
                          COL4, COL5, COL6
                     FROM TABLE4) q4
    ON q4.RNUM = q3.RNUM;
```

In this way you get the data from query #4 to the right of the rows from query #3.

[SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bb015/1)

Answer (score 1):

IF you want formatting of output you need to use either the `UTL_FILE` package or the `DBMS_OUTPUT` package - to write to files or the tty respectively.   `UTL_FILE` may require your DBA to make an addition to the `ALL_DIRECTORIES` view so your directory object is defined.  In other words you cannot just write to any folder you want.

These packages use syntax for output somewhat akin to C `printf` statements.
See: 
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA

Answer (score 0):

Consider this a 'partial' answer.

I'm the Product Manager for Oracle SQL Developer, and we have a new utility, SQLcl.

You can set your SQLFORMAT to CSV or to HTML.

Any resultset is automatically formatted to that, no extra coding required.

It's still in beta, hence the partial status.

[Slidedeck and video here.](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/oracle-sqlcl-slidedeck-overview-of-our-new-command-line-interface/)